# Overriding base Silverlight controls to display only text

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to create custom controls derived from the framework controls that have the added functionality of rendering themselves as a TextBlock. I'm doing this because the built-in IsEnabled or IsReadOnly properties don't meet my needs. However, I don't see any overridable methods in the control that would give me the functionality I need.

Am I headed down the right path? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using data templates? You could have a data template selector choose the correct data template based on whatever condition. One template could be for read only and the other for editable... for exmaple.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly your needs are? Why a normal `TextBlock` doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this example is thrown together - keep that in mind. You'll notice that Im using some telerik controls... but you should be able to get the gist of what im doing. Also, in this example i threw together, im not using a DataTemplateSelector... just selecting the template in the code behind.

Rough sketch of xaml...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Admin.ManagePositions"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ReadPositionTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PositionCode}" Style="{StaticResource H5}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <telerik:RadButton  x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit"  Click="btnEdit_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditPositionCommand, ElementName=ucManagePositions}" />
                    <telerik:RadButton  x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete Position" Style="{StaticResource AutoSizeButton}" Click="btnDelete_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeletePositionCommand, ElementName=ucManagePositions}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditPositionTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <sdk:Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtPositionCode}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPositionCode" Text="{Binding PositionCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <telerik:RadButton  x:Name="btnSaveEdit" Content="Save"  Click="btnSaveEdit_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.SavePositionCommand, ElementName=ucManagePositions}" />
                    <telerik:RadButton  x:Name="btnCancelEdit" Content="Cancel"   Click="btnCancelEdit_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.ResetHighlightPositionCommand, ElementName=ucManagePositions}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadTransitionControl x:Name="selectedPositionContainer" Loaded="selectedPositionContainer_Loaded" Content="{Binding HighlightedPosition}">
            <telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>
                <telerik:SlideAndZoomTransition />
            </telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>
        </telerik:RadTransitionControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And a rough outline of the code behind:

```
namespace Admin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ManagePositions : UserControl      {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTemplate dt = ucManagePositions.Resources["EditPositionTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            selectedPositionContainer.ContentTemplate = dt;
        }

        private void btnCancelEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTemplate dt = ucManagePositions.Resources["ReadPositionTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            selectedPositionContainer.ContentTemplate = dt;
        }
        private void selectedPositionContainer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTemplate dt = ucManagePositions.Resources["ReadPositionTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            selectedPositionContainer.ContentTemplate = dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope that helps!